# can't display table in multiple textbox

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I must go through the records of a table and display them in multiple textboxes
I am using the table with four different alias to have four workareas on the same table and have four record pointers.

```
USE Customers ALIAS customers1 
USE customers AGAIN ALIAS customers2
USE customers AGAIN ALIAS customers3
USE customers AGAIN ALIAS customers4

Thisform.TxtNomCli.ControlSource = "customers.name"
Thisform.TxtIdent.ControlSource = "customers.identify"
Thisform.TxtAddress.ControlSource = "customers.address"
Thisform.TxtTele.ControlSource = "customers.phone"

Thisform.TxtNomCli2.ControlSource = "customers2.name"
Thisform.TxtIdent2.ControlSource = "customers2.identify"
Thisform.TxtDirec2.ControlSource = "customers2.address"
Thisform.TxtTele2.ControlSource = "customers2.phone"

Thisform.TxtNomCli3.ControlSource = "customers3.name"
Thisform.TxtIdent3.ControlSource = "customers3.identify"
Thisform.TxtDirec3.ControlSource = "customers3.address"
Thisform.TxtTele3.ControlSource = "customers3.phone"


Thisform.TxtNomCli4.ControlSource = "customers4.name"
Thisform.TxtIdent4.ControlSource = "customers4.identify"
Thisform.TxtDirec4.ControlSource = "customers4.address"
Thisform.TxtTele4.ControlSource = "customers4.phone"
```

[image: main display]

how to go through the records of the table, that in customers is in the first record, customers2 in the second record, customers3 in the third record and customers4 in the fourth record of the table?

[image: table]

How do I make each row of the textbox show the corresponding row of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I would SQL Select id + whatever other fields you need into four cursors:

```
select id, identifica, nombre, direccion, telefono from customers ;
into cursor customers1 nofilter readwrite

select id, identifica, nombre, direccion, telefono from customers;
into cursor customers2 nofilter readwrite

* repeat for 3 and 4
```

Then set your ControlSources() to the cursors, not the base table. If you need to update records you can use the id of the modified record in the cursor to update the correct record in the base table.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use SET RELATION to achieve what you want. However, in your current code you are not really using 4 aliases. You are reopening the same table with a different alias in the same workarea and you would end up with a single table with alias Customers4. To do that correctly, you need to add "IN 0" clause to your USE commands. ie:

```
USE customers ALIAS customers1 
USE customers IN 0 AGAIN ALIAS customers2
USE customers IN 0 AGAIN ALIAS customers3
USE customers IN 0 AGAIN ALIAS customers4

SELECT customers1
SET RELATION TO ;
    RECNO()+1 INTO Customers2, ;
    RECNO()+2 INTO Customers3, ;
    RECNO()+3 INTO Customers4 IN Customers1
```

With this setup, as you move the pointer in Customers1 it would move in all other 3 aliases accordingly (note that there is no order set).

Having said these, now you should think why you need to do this? Maybe having another control like a grid is the way to go? Or using an array might be a better way to control this? ie: With an array:

```
USE (_samples+'data\customer') ALIAS customers 

LOCAL ARRAY laCustomers[4]
LOCAL ix
FOR ix=1 TO 4
    GO m.ix
    SCATTER NAME laCustomers[m.ix]
ENDFOR

? laCustomers[1].Cust_id, laCustomers[2].Cust_id, laCustomers[3].Cust_id, laCustomers[4].Cust_id
```

With this approach, you could set your controlsources to be laCustomers[1].Identify, laCustomers[1].name and so on. While saving back to data, you would go to related record and do a GATHER. That would be all.

First you need to think about what you really want to do.